# 403 Forbidden When Pushing Docker Image to GitHub Registry (ghcr.io)

Tags: docker, github, yaml, github-actions, workflow

When using my GitHub action that creates a Docker image and pushes it, it gets 403 forbidden whilst trying to push to GitHub's registry. It works fine with Docker Hub:

```
 Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to push ghcr.io/***/kernelos_buildtools:main: unexpected status from POST request to https://ghcr.io/v2/***/kernelos_buildtools/blobs/uploads/: 403 Forbidden
```

My GitHub workflow:

```yaml
name: Docker

# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '44 0 * * *'
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
    # Publish semver tags as releases.
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  release:
    types: [published]

env:
  # Sets the Docker registry
  DOCKER_REGISTRY: docker.io
  # Sets the GitHub registry
  GITHUB_REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  # github.repository as <account>/<repo>
  IMAGE_NAME: minionguyjpro/kernelos_buildtools


jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
      # This is used to complete the identity challenge
      # with sigstore/fulcio when running outside of PRs.
      id-token: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Install the cosign tool except on PR
      # https://github.com/sigstore/cosign-installer
      - name: Install cosign
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: sigstore/cosign-installer@v3.0.2
        with:
          cosign-release: 'v1.11.0'


      # Workaround: https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/461
      - name: Setup Docker buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2.5.0

      # Login against the Docker registry except on PR
      # https://github.com/docker/login-action
      - name: Log into registry ${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY }}
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/login-action@v2.1.0
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
          
      
      # Login against the GitHub registry except on PR
      # https://github.com/docker/login-action
      - name: Log into registry ${{ env.GITHUB_REGISTRY }}
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/login-action@v2.1.0
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.GITHUB_REGISTRY }}
          username: The-Kernel-Brothers
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      # Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
      # https://github.com/docker/metadata-action
      - name: Extract Docker metadata (Docker Registry)
        id: meta_docker
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4.4.0
        with:
          images: ${{ env.DOCKER_REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
          
      # Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
      # https://github.com/docker/metadata-action
      - name: Extract Docker metadata (GitHub Registry)
        id: meta_github
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4.4.0
        with:
          images: ${{ env.GITHUB_REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}

      # Build and push Docker image with Buildx (don't push on PR)
      # https://github.com/docker/build-push-action
      - name: Build and push Docker image (Docker registry)
        id: build-and-push_docker
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4.0.0
        with:
          context: .
          push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
          tags: ${{ steps.meta_docker.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta_docker.outputs.labels }}
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
        if:  ${{ github.event_name != 'release' }}
          
      # Build and push Docker image with Buildx (don't push on PR)
      # https://github.com/docker/build-push-action
      - name: Build and push Docker image on release (Docker registry)
        id: build-and-push_docker_release
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4.0.0
        with:
          context: .
          push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
          tags: minionguyjpro/kernelos_buildtools:latest
          labels: ${{ steps.meta_docker.outputs.labels }}
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
        if: ${{ github.event_name == 'release' }}
          
      # Build and push Docker image with Buildx (don't push on PR)
      # https://github.com/docker/build-push-action
      - name: Build and push Docker image (GitHub registry)
        id: build-and-push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4.0.0
        with:
          context: .
          push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
          tags: ${{ steps.meta_github.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta_github.outputs.labels }}
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
        if: ${{ github.event_name != 'release' }}
      
      # Build and push Docker image with Buildx (don't push on PR)
      # https://github.com/docker/build-push-action
      - name: Build and push Docker image on release (GitHub registry)
        id: build-and-push_release
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4.0.0
        with:
          context: .
          push: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
          tags: ghcr.io/minionguyjpro/kernelos_buildtools:latest
          labels: ${{ steps.meta_github.outputs.labels }}
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
        if: ${{ github.event_name == 'release' }}
```

So I tried running the action like I said, but it fails when pushing to GitHub's registry, which I want to be able to do. The repository was first owned by me where pushing worked, but now it's in an organization where I have admin access to it just doesn't want to work anymore.